# NSWindowDelegate : windowDidBecomeKey vs windowDidBecomeMain

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow, nsnotifications

What is the difference between **windowDidBecomeKey:** and **windowDidBecomeMain:** notifications?

In other words, I want to know that "what is the key window" and "what is the main window".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/ChangingMainKeyWindow.html)

> Windows have different looks based on how the user is interacting with
>   them. The foremost document or application window that is the focus of
>   the user’s attention is referred to as the main window. Each
>   application also has only one main window at a given time. This main
>   window often has key status, as well. The main window is the principal
>   focus of user actions for an application. Often, user actions in a
>   modal key window (typically a panel such as the Font window or an Info
>   window) have a direct effect on the main window.

as an example (always from the documentation)

> A good example of the difference between key and main windows can be
>   seen in most well-behaved Mac apps. Selecting “Save As...” in a text
>   document, for example, displays a panel with a field to type the
>   document’s name and a pull-down menu of locations to save it. The
>   panel represents the key window. It will accept your keyboard input
>   (the file name), but will directly affect the main window under it (by
>   saving it to the location you specified). Once you save the document,
>   the save panel disappears, the main window becomes key again, and will
>   accept keyboard input once more.